# First time trying I'm working on Login/register form. Getting an error

Tags: php, authentication

Hey guys I'm working on a login/register for and I'm struggeling with the following things. When registering there's a message (registration complete) but there's also an error I can't get rid off.

Als when the username is already taken there should be a message that says that but there isn't. The error I get is the following.

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool 
given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\registration.php on line 16
```

The code I use in registration.php is

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','jstam','12345');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration'); 

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = "select * from usertable where name = 'name' && passoword = '$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
echo"Gebruikersnaam in gebruik";
}else{
$reg= "insert into usertable (name , password) values ('$name' , '$pass')";
mysqli_query($con, $reg);
echo"Registratie succevol";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks.  **You will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries.  Never concatenate arbitrary data into an SQL query.  Additionally, don't store passwords in your database.  If your database is stolen, then everyone's passwords vulnerable.  Use a proper hashing mechanism.  PHP has a nice provision for this.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: You probably don't have a column named passoword

Comment: your query is return false so. You have typo in query. It should be $name not name. Here `$s = "select * from usertable where name = '$name' //here && passoword = '$pass'";`

Comment: `$_POST['user'] = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 --"` - that is what I would do...  Then your login will work.  If you add `OFFSET` to that it will work for any user in your DB!  Well after you change `name = 'name'` to `name='$name'` anyway.

Comment: It's less intuitive to use `&&` and more error prone `&`  then using `AND` SQL is meant to be somewhat human readable.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ...deleting my useless comment after you told me and I figuered it out anyway. I learned something ;)

Comment: PD of [mysql\_fetch\_array()/mysql\_fetch\_assoc()/mysql\_fetch\_row()/mysql\_num\_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource or result](//stackoverflow.com/q/2973202) / [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174) / [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments](//stackoverflow.com/q/22662488) / [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](//stackoverflow.com/q/401656)

Comment: One thing.... what you are doing is a bad idea... don't include the password=? in your test query because anyone can then run a BRUTE FORCE ATTACK on any users data, by inputting a random password to check for a password match for any given user already in your database.

Comment: Also use SELECT COUNT(*) AS total... instead of mysqli_num_rows() as it's more optimized than using mysqli_num_rows()

Comment: Thanks guys, learning a lot here. I'll start working on it. It's my first time playing with php so thanks!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Can you ellaborate some more about this? Where to put this , I need to learn all about it. Thnx!

Comment: @StephanieTemple password=? Where do you see it. I do see when I try to login that the details I entered are in the URL box.

Comment: @StephanieTemple - that is not the reason to not search the DB by password. It's not a cryptographically  secure way to compare hashes. Even in PHP you should use something like `password_verify()` or `hash_equals()` etc.  I can brute force a password regardless if its in PHP or MySql.  Sorry to correct you but it's a important distinction.  It's also harder to bypass the login when SQL injection happens, but that should never happen with prepared statements.

Comment: If you do a sql attack against a system that matches the password only in the DB, you can bypass that by modifying the query. Generally so it returns a single user row.  But if they also check the password in PHP, you have to know the password which kills your chance of bypassing the login.   Sorry for the long description.  -- if you want to prevent BRUTE force attacks you have to limit the number of failed login attempts per account. With some time to reset.  That makes it take a zillion years to brute force it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You seem to know a lot and love that! Would like to come in contact with you for some further help if you are okay with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may have a typo in your code

```
$s = "select * from usertable where name = 'name' && passoword = '$pass'";
```

I assume that passoword should be password. Also, name should be $name

```
$s = "select * from usertable where name = '$name' && password = '$pass'";
```

As others have suggested, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and should NOT be used in production.

Comment: It's only for practice purposes, every noob has to start somewhere right, thanks! ;)

Comment: I completely agree! This wasn't meant to scare you but it is surprisingly common to see sites with SQL injection vulnerabilities. Good luck and happy coding! (And if this answered your question dont forget to mark as correct :] )

Comment: I'm currently working on a different one using hashing to make it more secure.. later I want to add a Max to login attempts. Any advice on how to make a registration/login form more secure?

Comment: I currently run the following code for registration and hashing the passwords into the database, everything seems to work and after registering there's nothing coming up in the DB. What could be wrong.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, there are endless amounts of things that could be going wrong.  Your best bet is to open up a new question and somebody could help. It is difficult to assist without having a look at the code and some context of what you are trying to accomplish.